# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError Netbeans

Tags: java

I have 3 files in my project, 2 class files and the main file. I get this error when I use netbeans and run the code.

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError*

This is the code in my main file:

```
package ejercicio1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal {
    private static Scanner teclado;
    //private static Persona persona;
    private static Alumno alumno;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    // Inicializamos el objeto para reservar espacio en memoria RAM
    //persona = new Persona();
    alumno = new Alumno();
    teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Vamos solicitando al usuario cada dato y guardandolo en el objeto
// creado
    System.out.print("Introduce el nombre: ");
    **alumno.setNombre(teclado.nextLine());**

    System.out.print("Introduce los apellidos: "); 
    alumno.setApellidos(teclado.nextLine());

    System.out.print("Introduce la edad: ");
    alumno.setEdad(teclado.nextInt());

    System.out.print("Introduce el curso: ");
    alumno.setCurso(teclado.nextLine());

    System.out.println();

    // Mostramos por pantalla los datos guardados en el objeto

    System.out.println(alumno.getNombre() + " " + alumno.getApellidos() + " tiene " + alumno.getEdad() + " años y cursa " + alumno.getCurso());
}

}
```

The error shows at this line: alumno.setNombre(teclado.nextLine());

**This is my alumno.java file:**

```
package ejercicio1;

public class Alumno extends Persona {
   // Definimos la variable propia de esta clase
    private String curso;

    // Creamos el constructor
public Alumno() {

}

    // Definimos el getter y setter de la variable
    public void setCurso(String curso){
        this.curso = curso;
    }

    public String getCurso(){
        return curso;
    }
}
```

**And this is my Persona.java file**

```
package ejercicio1;
public class Persona {
    String nombre, apellidos;
int edad;

    public Persona() {
    // No le pasamos parámetros ya que no es necesario
}

    public void setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos){
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad){
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidos(){
        return apellidos;
    }

    public int getEdad(){
        return edad;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line does the exception occur on? Can you paste the Alumno class as well?

Comment: You've typed one of your method calls incorrectly

Comment: Can you show us the setNombre method in the Alumno class?

Comment: Have you recompiled the Alumno class after adding `extends Persona` ?

Comment: @SaviourSelf Yeah I sure did and I still get the same error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ejercicio1.Alumno.setNombre(Ljava/lang/String;)V
 at ejercicio1.Principal.main(Principal.java:23)

Comment: @MONZTAAA That's odd, I reproduced your code locally and it works. On another note, you're missing a closing brace on your Principal class.